# Unable to change the x and y position of Label inside navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, label, uinavigationbar

I am building an app that uses a custom navigation bar as shown in this pic

[image: my imaage]

I am unable to change the the position of the label such as "My Xyz business". I want to push the label a little top of the screen ( right now its hugging towards the bottom of the bar)

i have tried with code but only the height and width changes. There is no change in the x and y position.

Why is that happening

following is the code:

func customNavigationBar() {

```
    var ver: [AnyObject] = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    if CInt(ver[0] as! String)! >= 7 {
        // iOS 7.0 or later
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
    }
    else {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }


    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,400 , 174)

    let lbl: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30))
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Vodafone Rg", size: 20.0)

    lbl.text = "My Xyz Inc Business"
    lbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 230.0 / 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    let vodafoneLabel: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: lbl)
```

Comment: which label you want to change in the above screenshot

Comment: lbl.text = "My Xyz Inc Business" this one... i want it to move a bit up since this is hugging the bottom line. i tried to change the x and y position but no matter what i try it still remains at the same place.

Comment: just change the frame of the lbl;but remember the height  cannot be more than 64,otherwise it will clip over the viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepraj, will try that and let you know.. I have one more issue that needs attention.. In the previous given pic you can see account summary (in red) that is actually a scroll bar . i would like to display a red line when any particular segment control is selected. how to achieve this .

Comment: what kinda issue?